# Administrator has no admin bar for specific pages

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have an issue with a dotnetnuke 7 site, where the administrator cannot edit a minority of the pages.

When logged in and on such a page, the edit page menu missing.

When on the page management view, there are only options to view or make homepage. On clicking, properties are not shown.

What could be causing this?

Cheers, mark

Answer (score 0):

I've seen in the past where the Administrator Role Id is incorrectly defined in the database.

Unfortunately there isn't a UI way to change this, you'll need to go into the DB to see what Role ID is defined. I believe AdministratorRoleID is stored either in the Portals table, or in the PortalSettings or PortalLocalization table. Check the # and see if that matches the ID of the Administrators role for that portal.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a CSS issue if it only affects some pages. Can you try changing the skin on those pages to the default skin and try again...

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this old question, so I thought that I'd update with what the actual problem was.

We imported pages using a direct to database program - we naturally assumed that the site administrator could, as a default be able to edit pages within their own site.

As it turns out, DNN actually creates correct access rights to each page as they are created, and rights are added and removed as required. This means that if you create pages you must directly create access rights for the correct site administrator.

Kind Regards, Mark, [IA](http://www.ia.uk.com)